# LINQ Order By Descending with Null Values on Bottom

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have this expression:

```
troubletickets = db.ServiceTickets.Include(t => t.Company).Include(t => t.UserProfile);
troubletickets.OrderByDescending(t => t.UserProfile != null ? t.UserProfile.FirstName : "ZZZ");
```

I have to check if UserProfile is null because if I don't I will get an error. The problem is, sometimes UserProfiles.FirstName can be null. When it is null, those values are placed at the top of the list when I order by both ascending and descending. E.g.

```
// Null, Null, Andy, Bill, Chris
// Null, Null, Chris, Bill, Andy
```

How can I alter this expression so that when I order by descending it returns something like this instead:

```
// Chris, Bill, Andy, Null, Null
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You almost had it right:

```
troubletickets.OrderByDescending(t => t.UserProfile != null
                                      && t.UserProfile.FirstName != null
                                         ? t.UserProfile.FirstName
                                         : string.Empty);
```

`string.Empty` will always be the *lowest* string, so it will end up last in an `OrderByDescending`.

If you want something that works with both ascending and descending order, you'd have to sort in two steps:

```
troubletickets.OrderByDescending(t => t.UserProfile != null
                                      && t.UserProfile.FirstName != null)
              .ThenByDescending(t => t.UserProfile != null                // Or ThenBy
                                         ? t.UserProfile.FirstName
                                         : null);
```

This works because `true > false`.

Comment: This suggestion worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

What you can do to handle it in the general case is to first order by whether or not the value is null, and *then* order based on the value itself as a tiebreaker.

```
troubletickets = troubletickets.OrderBy(t => t.UserProfile != null)
   .ThenByDescending(t => t.UserProfile);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are close to it

```
 OrderByDescending(t => t.UserProfile != null ? t.UserProfile.FirstName : "ZZZ")
```

Here, you are stating that if `t.userProfile` is `null`, it should be considered as if its value was `ZZZ`. Just make the same for `t.userProfile.FirstName`.

```
 OrderByDescending(t => t.UserProfile != null ?
   t.UserProfile.FirstName ?? "ZZZ" :
   "ZZZ")
```

The "??" is the coalesce operator (if left statement is not null, use left statement, else use right statement)